# C# MVC Mapping all routes to a frontcontroller

Tags: c#, razor, front-controller

I'm trying to use the "maproute" function to map all routes to one controller. So far it's not working.

I have several razor views (.cshtml) that I want to go through one controller. I try to use the following code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "FrontController", 
           action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But this simply fires the specific controller with the same name as the view. For instance if the view is called BannedBatches, this would fire a controller called BannedBatchesController.

I want all requests to go through the FrontController. Is this possible ?

Edit: I tried using the code in the "duplicate" question:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "ReallyBadIdea",
            "{*url}",
            new { controller = "FrontController", action = "Index" }
            );
```

It's still giving me a 404 request error.

[image]

Comment: I updated the OP. This solution is not working.